# How to morph dynamically generated images

Tags: jquery

I have a form where a user is able to make selections and then based on these selections a graph is dynamically generated and shown as an image.

At the moment I am doing this by displaying the image in a jQuery dialog.

Is it possible to put something together (ideally using jQuery) so that when one image is being displayed and the user submits another selection, the first image directly morphs into the second image without showing an intermediate and unnecessary background view?

Comment: It depends on how you are drawing the image on the first place. But it would not be easy

Comment: Poorly asked question. (-1) -- You are either clearly asking someone to write you this piece of code ( this is not code request website ), or you are asking a question that just doesn't help anyone. "Q: Is is possible? A: Yes. -- Now what?"

Answer (score 0):

You could position two images on top of each other inside the dialog (set position to absolute and use z-index) and when the 2nd image has loaded, animate the alpha from one to the other. This should work.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I will Google alpha to see what this may involve. I am aware of the jQuery cycle and have just found that it supports before/after callbacks and click triggers - whatever this means.

Comment: Callbacks look promising under the section titled "Callbacks" at [JQuery Cycle Plugin - Intermediate Demos (Part 2)](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html)

Comment: You can use jQuery methods `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut`

Comment: In fact, I plan to try to implement this today. Unless I have overlooked something stupid, and if I remember, I will post back here to report how it went.

Comment: Hi Spezi. When I tried this earlier today I kept getting the unnecessary initial content in the div which I replace with the content in my dialog after the using makes a first selection to dynamically generate an image. I will have another look to see if I have not overlooked something. I may post some code if I have no joy.

Comment: Hi Spezi. I have just had a look at the jQuery fadeIn and fadeOut method examples at [jQuery Effects - Fading](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_fade.asp). It looks like these methods do as they say and fade out to the background and fade in from the background. This is not what I want because I do not want the user to wait for the background to appear. I want the two images to morph which is a much quicker process because it does not involve showing the intermediate background.

Comment: Just fadeOut the one image and at the same time, fadeIn the other image, it will crossfade.

Comment: Hi Spezi. Thank you for pointing this out to me. I see that the jQuery cycle plugin morphs 2 images with the following code.

Comment: @david_zzzz If you use css to pile up those two images and hide the one on top, all you'd have to do, is to fade that top image in and out. Makes the code a bit lighter as well.

Comment: Thanks Joonas and Spezi for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for pointing out to me that the jQuery methods fadeIn and fadeOut crossfade. I see that the jQuery cycle plugin morphs 2 images with the following code. However I see that your solution directly uses jQuery methods so in this respect your solution may be more attractive.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#crossfade').cycle();
});
</script>
<div id="crossfade">
    <img src="1.jpg" />
    <img src="2.jpg" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the end for my graph application I went with a solution which showed a busy message before fading in the new image. This was largely because I was dynamically generating the images using the jpgraph library and I was not sure how I could accommodate these dynamically created images in a morphing solution.

Comment: Sorry if my comments do not follow etiquette. I am still learning the ropes.